# Assigning void to double pointer

Tags: c, void

I need to understand why assigning `void*` to `int**` will work, but when printing the value of `int**`, it will not work. Here's the code:

```
int k = 3;
int *l = &k;
void *a = l; 
int **c = a; // if I assign, &a, the below line work, but get warning: incompatible
             // pointer type.
printf("%d", **c); // Code break;
```

But this line

```
printf("%d", *c); // will work, but get warning "%d expect int but of type int *".
```

**Update:** I saw this type of code in `OOC book` where author do this:

```
struct Class {
   size_t size;
   int (*differ)(const void *self, const void *b);
   ..... Some more code ....

};

int differ(const void *self, const void *b) {
  // Note this line
  const struct Class **cp = self;
  assert(self && *cp && (*cp)->differ);
  return (*cp)->differ(self, b);
}
```

Comment: **c will try to read an integer from the address '3'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this situation:

```
+---+
| l | --\
+---+    \     +---+
          >--> | k |
+---+    /     +---+
| a | --/
+---+
```

I.e. both `l` and `a` points directly to `k`.

When you then do

```
int **c = a;
```

you make `c` point to what `a` is pointing to as well (i.e. it's the same as doing `int **c = &k`), but you declare `c` to be a pointer to pointer to an `int`, but make it point directly to an `int`. That means using single dereference (`*c`) you get the value of `k`, and when you you use double dereference (`**c`) you use the value of `k` as a pointer (which it isn't).

I assume what you really want is this situation:

```
+---+     +---+     +---+
| a | --> | l | --> | k |
+---+     +---+     +---+
```

which you will get by doing

```
void *a = &l;
```

Then using `c` as a pointer to pointer will work because then `a` is a pointer to a pointer.

---

If you continue with the first scenario, where you have

```
int   k;
int  *l = &k;
void *a = l;
```

and then do

```
int **c = (int **) &a;  // The typecast is needed
```

Then you have the following situation:

```
          +---+
          | l | --\
          +---+    \     +---+
                    >--> | k |
+---+     +---+    /     +---+
| c | --> | a | --/
+---+     +---+
```

This will work because then `c` really *is* a pointer to a pointer to something.

Comment: your last line `void *a = &l`. If i use this, then i have to use `int **c = a`, which would work. But see `c` is assigned `a` not address of a`. Can you please illustrate this.

Comment: @ashish2expert Updated my answer, see the end of it.

Comment: Ain't `void *a = &l;` issue warning, since type of `&l` is `(int **)` while `a` is `void*`?

Answer (score 2):

This is why you have to be careful with `void*` pointers. You can assign *any* pointer to them, and you can assign them to *any* other pointer. Even if it doesn't make sense (like your example).

When you assign `int **c = a`, you've committed an error, that I think you're already aware of. You've changed levels of indirection (`a` came from an `int*`, but you're assigning it to an `int**`), but didn't take another address-of (`&`).

Your program fails for the same reason that, if you eliminated the `void* a`, and instead tried this, it would fail.

```
int k = 3;
int *l = &k;
int **c = l;    // Error - wrong level of indirection.
```

This is low-level C. Just because the compiler lets you do something doesn't mean it will work.

The solution to this question is: *Don't do it*.

Comment: I saw this type of code in `OOC book`, In that book, author assign `void *self` to `struct Class **cp = self`.

Comment: @ashish2expert Need more context for that to make sense.